# How to find and save the sum of a variable from a specific list of turtles, Netlogo?

Tags: list, netlogo

How would you find the sum a turtle specific variable from a list of turtles?

I'm trying to sum a variable from a list of turtles and compare that sum to the asking turtle's specific value, but I'm not sure what the syntax would be.

Each turtle has it's own specific list composed of other turtles to ask `[mylist]`, and I'm looking to sum their `var_x` and compare it to the asking turtle's `var_x`.

```
ask turtles [
set ListVarXSum ( sum (var_x) of each turtle on list [mylist] )
]
```

Answer (score 3):

The most direct way to do what you want is:

```
set ListVarXSum sum map [ t -> [ var-x ] of t ] mylist
```

The [`map`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#map) primitive transforms the list of turtles into a list filled by the values of `var-x` for each of those turtles. You can then sum that list with `sum`.

That being said, Luke C is right that it's often more convenient to store agents in a agentset then in a list (unless you need them to be in a specific order or you have repeated agents).

To convert a list of agents into an agentset, you can always use the [`turtle-set`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#turtle-set) primitive. Using that, you could do:

```
set ListVarXSum sum [ var-x ] of turtle-set mylist
```

It reads nicer, but it runs slower because of the time needed to convert the list into an agentset every time. If it's an operation you need to do often, it's probably better to store an agentset up front (possibly by using `turtle-set` to convert whatever it is that you are putting in `mylist` into an agentset instead, or by using a primitive that gives you an agentset anyway, like Luke's `n-of` example.)

Comment: The `my_comparison_turtles` turtle-set that Luke C recommend works, but that creates a new list of turtles with every operation.  Project wise, I need to use a pre-built list of turtles.  Otherwise I would have to make the claim that this list is random every time, rather than the fixed list built around specific assumptions.

Is it possible to read in an agent-set using the `read-from-string` or other related commands from a txt / csv file?  That would work into my project, but at the moment every time I try this it creates an entirely new set of unrelated turtles.

Comment: The breed I'm working with I'm calling `breed [households household]`.

Comment: Or, as a thought, would it be possible to use a list of agent attributes, like say `who`?  So something like.... `set ListVarXSum sum [ var-x ] of turtles with [[who] of myself = mylist]`   So if I have a `mylist` of `[5 10 30]`, it would use agents 5, 10 and 30?

Comment: First, building a list of `who` numbers is a ***very very bad idea***, for more reasons that I can fit into this comment. If you are dealing with agents, use a list of agents or an agentset. That being said, I'm not sure I understand your problem. If you're building your list or agentset in `setup`, you're not building it "with every operation". Just once per simulation run. If what you're worried is having different agents from run to run, then, yeah, you could use the [`csv`](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html) extension to load data from CSV, but it may not be necessary.

Comment: If you're wondering how to initialize your simulation with a "fixed list built on specific assumptions", I would suggest you ask a separate question (with some details about the kind of assumptions you need to make). There are ways to do that, but this is getting too long for comments.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand what you're after, it might be easiest to not use a list of turtles but to use an agentset of the turtles to compare against instead. Have a look at this simple example and see if it accomplishes what you need:

```
turtles-own [ 
  var_x 
  my_comparison_turtles 
]

to setup
  ca
  crt 10 [
    set var_x 3 + random 10
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]

  ask turtles [
    set my_comparison_turtles n-of 3 other turtles
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to sum-compare

  ask turtles [
    let temp_sum sum [var_x] of my_comparison_turtles
    print ( word "My var_x is " var_x ", and the sum of my comparison turtles' var_x is " temp_sum "." )
  ]

end
```